# why does error "Attribute error: module 'myApp.views' has no attribute symbol" occur in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm using django framework for my app backend, I want to use the attribute ( which is fetched using get() method of request) from views.py file into another py file into same directory as views.py .
I am getting the following two errors mentioned below:

Error 1

```
 File "F:\pythonProject\mydjango\myApp\myApp\sub1.py", line 14, in tweets_kafka_main
    tweets_kafka_producer.my_main(views.symbol)
AttributeError: module 'myApp.views' has no attribute 'symbol'
```

Error 2:

```
File "F:\pythonProject\mydjango\myApp\myApp\spark_kafka_mysql.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

myApp/myApp/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import sub1
global symbol

def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")

def result(request):
    global symbol
    symbol = request.GET['St']
    pred_df= sub1.my_main()
    ans=pred_df.tail().to_html()
    return render(request,"result.html",{"ans":ans})
```

structure of directory

```
myApp
|-myApp
  |-views.py
  |-tweets_kafka_producer.py
  |-sub1.py
  |-spark_kafka_mysql.py
  |-__init__.py
  |-settings.py
  |-urls.py
```

Comment: Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. Instead, post it as text.

Comment: You don't seem to have an `__init__.py` file, which would explain the second error. As for the first error, you're probably trying to use the `symbol` variable before it has been created. In addition, I'd say global variables are generally a bad idea. Your project seems to have problems with its structure itself. You may want to reorganise your files and code.

Comment: I actually do have __init__.py file inside myApp/myApp along with wsgi.py,asgi.py ,settings.py (all these are default .py files created when we create a new project in django therefore I did not mention them). @Shinratensei

Comment: @Shinratensei could u please suggest any other way to use the attribute "symbol"  from views.py into tweets_kafka_producer.py file ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what you're trying to achieve in your project, so my suggestions might not be accurate. All I can tell you is that you're probably trying to use the `symbol` before the `result` function has been called. Try to find a way to make sure that `result` has been called before `tweets_kafka_producer.my_main(views.symbol)` is executed.